Interpretable measures of matrix non-normality?
How should I measure how non-normal my matrices are?
I'm interested in measures that have a practical interpretation -- "if the matrix non-normality measure is >x, then I need at least xyz bits of precision to do y"
Some non-normality measures I've seen:

sum of magnitudes of off-diagonal entries in the Schur decomposition, suggested by Nick Higham
Lyapunov condition factor (Theorem 10.1 of Lewis paper)

This Figure in 7.2 of Corless/Fillion book gives an example of slow convergence of Richardson on a non-normal linear system

Related question on math.SE: geometric intuition for non-normal matrix

I briefly looked at this topic back in 2012 and found in my Zotero the following seminal review paper "On measures of nonnormality of matrices". Don't have enough insight for an answer and will be watching this question as this topic is quite practical for some things I work with, but never have the time.

I have read Upper Bounds for Best Normal Approximation by Laszlo which conjectures the following:
$$
|A-N_n|_F \leq \frac{n-1}{n}(|A|_F - \sum_i |\lambda_i|^2).
$$ This isn’t very practical but it is another way of measuring the deviation

@whpowell96 there's a missing square on Frobenius norm. Easier way to remember the rightmost part is to write it in terms of singular value/eigenvalue magnitudes as $$\sum_i |\sigma_i|^2 - |\lambda_i|^2$$
